# Azure IoT Hub message count affectde by message size?

Tags: azure, windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to understand what affects Azure IoT Hub message counter.

I'm sending a simplae JSON formatted message from a Raspberry Pi 3 device running Windows IoT Core. The message size is probably around 1kb.

I have a simple Function that watches for new messages and stores them in a Table storage as they arrive.

Each message apprears to increment the Azure IoT Hub message counter by about 10 (rather than expected 1)

I have not found any reference to this - but does message size somewhow affects how messages are counted?

**EDIT**

The follwoing code sample once has just bumped up the message counter in Azure by 4

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static DeviceClient deviceClient;
        private static string iotHubUri = "iothubaccount.azure-devices.net";
        private static string deviceKey = "devicekey";

        private static string reading = @"{
cycle:0,
tempCentre:16.25,
trCentre:627,
tempCorner:16.00,
trCorner:619,
data: [
[{val: 643, convVal: 14.31, valA: 644}, {val: 1023, convVal: -94.70, valA: 1022}, {val: 628, convVal: 18.61, valA: 628}, {val: 620, convVal: 20.91, valA: 621}, {val: 622, convVal: 20.34, valA: 620}, {val: 621, convVal: 20.62, valA: 620}],
[{val: 645, convVal: 13.74, valA: 645}, {val: 1020, convVal: -93.84, valA: 1021}, {val: 630, convVal: 18.04, valA: 629}, {val: 620, convVal: 20.91, valA: 621}, {val: 620, convVal: 20.91, valA: 621}, {val: 621, convVal: 20.62, valA: 621}],
[{val: 644, convVal: 14.02, valA: 644}, {val: 1023, convVal: -94.70, valA: 1022}, {val: 627, convVal: 18.90, valA: 627}, {val: 620, convVal: 20.91, valA: 620}, {val: 621, convVal: 20.62, valA: 621}, {val: 620, convVal: 20.91, valA: 620}],
[{val: 667, convVal: 7.43, valA: 667}, {val: 1023, convVal: -94.70, valA: 1022}, {val: 733, convVal: -11.51, valA: 732}, {val: 644, convVal: 14.02, valA: 643}, {val: 645, convVal: 13.74, valA: 645}, {val: 644, convVal: 14.02, valA: 642}],
[{val: 644, convVal: 14.02, valA: 643}, {val: 1021, convVal: -94.13, valA: 1022}, {val: 628, convVal: 18.61, valA: 628}, {val: 619, convVal: 21.20, valA: 618}, {val: 619, convVal: 21.20, valA: 619}, {val: 618, convVal: 21.48, valA: 618}],
[{val: 665, convVal: 8.00, valA: 666}, {val: 1022, convVal: -94.42, valA: 1022}, {val: 648, convVal: 12.88, valA: 649}, {val: 644, convVal: 14.02, valA: 643}, {val: 644, convVal: 14.02, valA: 642}, {val: 643, convVal: 14.31, valA: 643}],
[{val: 1022, convVal: -94.42, valA: 1022}, {val: 1023, convVal: -94.70, valA: 1022}, {val: 1023, convVal: -94.70, valA: 1023}, {val: 1023, convVal: -94.70, valA: 1022}, {val: 1021, convVal: -94.13, valA: 1022}, {val: 1022, convVal: -94.42, valA: 1022}],
[{val: 651, convVal: 12.02, valA: 651}, {val: 1022, convVal: -94.42, valA: 1021}, {val: 654, convVal: 11.16, valA: 654}, {val: 627, convVal: 18.90, valA: 627}, {val: 628, convVal: 18.61, valA: 629}, {val: 629, convVal: 18.33, valA: 627}]
]}
";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending message.");
            deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(iotHubUri, new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey("RegistredDeviceName", deviceKey), TransportType.Mqtt);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reading));
            deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you get the message count? Which protocol did you use?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT using Mqtt protocol. Currently sending one message per minute and it seems to be using the entire 8000 message limit of free plan with one device in about 9 hours.

Comment: Did you count in your app of how many exactly messages did you sent in 9 hours?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT would have been around 650-700 messages. I'm also saving them to table storage and that also reflects that number.

Comment: Is there any other app sending messages to this iot hub?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample so I can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I have added the code sample into the original question. Replace the IoT hub address, device key and device name to appropriate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The follwoing code sample once has just bumped up the message counter
>   in Azure by 4

It is expected if you use iot hub free edition.

Based on your code sample, your message payload length is 2027(bytes). That will be divided to about 4 iot hub messages(For free edition [MESSAGE METER SIZE is 0.5 KB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/iot-hub/)).

You can get the message length using `message.BodyStream.Length`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was searching for message size limits and I couldn't find it anywhere. What are the message sizes for other tiers?